# для чего нужен указатель стека?

Tags: стек

он указывает на последний байт последнего элемента добавленного в стек и хранится в регистрах процессора.
Для чего он нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он указывает на вершину свободного места (стек заполняется вниз)

Нужен для адресации переменных, находящихся в стеке - локальных переменных, аргументов функций.

Да, забыл важное - про вызове функции (call somefunc) в стек кладётся адрес следующей после call инструкции - адрес возврата из функции

Comment: я правильно понял, при вызове функции в стеке сохраняется адрес, где была вызвана функция, что-бы при завершение функции можно было вернутся туда?

Comment: Да, верно.  Например: `320: call func;  324: что-то дальше;` здесь call неявно делает push 324

Comment: то есть в регистре хранится адреса переменных находящихся на стеке?

Comment: Нет. Регистр же содержит одно-единственное значение - только адрес  свободного места. Сами переменные лежат в стеке - области памяти с бОльшими адресами типа [esp+0x10]